# SAS program in Task Scheduler does not execute a subprocess using %sysexec

Tags: windows, powershell, sas, windows-task-scheduler

My Task Scheduler calls a Powershell script that starts a SAS program, which in turn executes a Windows command using %sysexec (and does a lot of other stuff on the side).

When I run the Powershell script interactively or start it manually in the Task Scheduler, the %sysexec command is executed correctly in the SAS program.

If the Powershell script is not started interactively by the Task Scheduler and I am not logged in on the computer, the %sysexec command is not executed. Nevertheless, it returns sysrc=0 as a result (success).

On the old machine with Windows Server 2012 it worked, on the new machine with Windows 2019 it does not.

I have written a highly simplified example here.

Task Scheduler Action:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass "C:\temp\test_sas.ps1"
```

Powershell Script test_sas.ps1:

```
$sasrootdirStr = "D:\sas\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4"
$pgmdirStr = "C:\temp"
$pgmnameStr= "test_sas"
$logdirStr = "C:\temp"
$logfileStr = $logdirStr + "\" + $pgmnameStr + ".log"
& "$sasrootdirStr\sas.exe" "$pgmdirStr\$pgmnameStr.sas" -log "$logfileStr"
```

SAS program test_sas.sas:

```
%macro test_sas;
   %local macroname;
   %let macroname= test_sas;
   %let newdir = %str(C:\temp\martin);
   %let sysrc = -1;
   %sysexec "mkdir" &newdir..; 
   %if &sysrc ne 0 %then %do;
      %put ERROR: &macroname: Could not execute command mkdir (sysrc: &sysrc.).;
   %end;
   %put sysrc: &sysrc;
%mend test_sas;
%test_sas;
```

Result in logfile test_sas.log (the %sysexec command mkdir was not executed):

```
sysrc: 0
NOTE: SAS Institute Inc, SAS Campus Drive, Cary, NC USA 27513-2414
NOTE: The SAS System used:
      real time 0.60 seconds
      cpu time 0.68 seconds
```

Used software versions:

new (with error):

- SAS 9.04.01M7P080520
- Windows Server 2019 Standard Version 1809
- Powershell 5.1.17763.2931

old (without errors):

- SAS 9.04.01M4P110916
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- Powershell 4.0

What is wrong?

Comment: `mkdir` is not an executable. Try `%sysexec cmd /c mkdir &newdir;`

Comment: In actual script (not simplified here), what was the subprocess and if it is not SAS specific, why use SAS and not PowerShell itself?

Comment: Did you trying using PIPE instead of %SYSEXEC so your SAS code can retrieve any messages the operating system is outputting in response to your attempt to run a command?  `data _null_; infile "mkdir ""&newdir""" pipe; input; put _infile_; run;`

Comment: It looks like you may have downgraded a SAS version as well? Your old server shows 9.4M7 while your new server shows 9.4M4. I don't know if that's the cause but it could be a factor.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Old SAS version was 9.04.01M4, new version is  9.04.01M7.

Comment: In the actual script I use SAS to perform some database transactions. The Powershell script is needed only to perform some administrative activities before and after calling SAS. In the SAS program I need to execute some Windows commands in subprocesses, e.g. start another SAS session, delete or move some files with Powershell or Xcopy, transfer some files with winscp.com.

Comment: With `%sysexec cmd /c mkdir` the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code for the powershell script works.
Instead of using the call operator (&), I can use the start-process comandlet. The %sysexec command in the child SAS program will then execute correctly under all circumstances, even if it is triggered in a task scheduler action.

Powershell script test_sas.ps1:

```
$process = (Start-Process -FilePath "$sasrootdirStr\sas.exe" -ArgumentList "`"$pgmdirStr\$pgmnameStr.sas`" -log `"$logfileStr`"" -PassThru -Wait)
Write-Host "Process terminated with return code: " $process.ExitCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data _null_; infile "mkdir ""&newdir""" pipe; input; put _infile_; run;
```

works. But the result code of the datastep is always zero (syserr=0, success), even if the windows command could not be successfully executed.

How can I get a useful return value from the command executed in the pipe? I really need this one.